# ¿Cómo mando los datos a una clase en C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
class persona{
    char *nombre,*direccion;
    int edad;
    public:
        persona(char *n,char *d,int c);
        ~persona();
        void mostrar_persona();
};
persona::persona(char *n,char *d,int c){
    nombre=n;
    direccion=d;
    edad=c;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    persona p1=persona("edwin","desconocida",20);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo haces de la forma:

```
persona p1((char*)"edwin", (char*)"desconocida", 20);
```

O su equivalente:

```
persona p1 = persona((char*)"edwin", (char*)"desconocida", 20);
```

O con el uso de la memoría dinámica:

```
persona *p1 = new persona((char*)"edwin", "desconocida", 20);
```

Otra cosa, la próxima vez, estructura mejor tu pregunta, y utiliza la combinación (Control + K) en tu código para mejor presentación.

Comment: gracias gracias no soy muy bueno con esto pero seguire tus consejos

Comment: Segun la forma que lo tiene estructurado que no funciona

Comment: no me funciona tengo mal el codigo?

Comment: Si editas la pregunta colocando el error que obtienes, sería más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: persona p1("edwin", "desconocida", 20); me da error

Comment: persona p1("edwin", "desconocida", 20); me da error tendre mal el codigo hecho?

Comment: Me refería al error que te arroja el compilador.

Comment: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'[-Wwrite-strings]

Comment: La solución es declarar el objeto pasando los argumentos 'char*' de esta forma: persona p1((char*)"edwin", (char*)"desconocida", 20); También asegúrate de darle cuerpo al destructor, así como lo hiciste con el constructor. Si no lo necesitas, déjalo vacío; pero tienes que darle cuerpo al destructor si declaras el prototipo dentro de la clase.

Comment: pero a todo esto que es lo hace este programa?

Comment: solo mandar a imprimir el nombre la direccion y la edad

Comment: "*No se coloca `persona p1=persona(...)`*" ¿Desde cuando? Es otra forma de construir objetos... prueba a compilar un ejemplo por favor

Comment: Oh, acabo de hacer la prueba y sí compila de tal forma. My bad. Siempre he construido de la forma Persona p([params]). Ya corrijo la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Una cadena cualquiera, por ejemplo `"abcd"` es un literal **constante** y tu estás intentando almacenar una referencia al mismo desde un puntero no constante... Fíjándonos solamente en esto la clase tendría que estar declarada así:

```
class persona{
    const char *nombre, *direccion;
};
```

Aun así sigues teniendo un problema... ¿qué sucede si lo que le pasas a la clase no es un literal sino un dato leído del teclado?

```
struct test
{
  const char* cadena;
};

int main()
{
  test t;

  char texto[200];
  std::cout << "Introduce un nombre: ";
  std::cin >> texto;
  t.cadena = texto;
  std::cout << "Introduce otro nombre: ";
  std::cin >> texto;

  std::cout << "El primer nombre es: " << t.cadena << '\n';
}
```

El problema es que la clase almacena un puntero... y el puntero no guarda una copia de los datos sino que simplemente apunta a ellos... cualquiera puede modificar esa posición de memoria sin que te enteres... En resumen, la clase necesitaría guardar una copia de las cadenas, y aquí nos encontramos con un dilema:

- ¿Deberíamos declarar arrays de tamaño fijo? En ese caso tendremos una limitación de base (no podremos almacenar cadenas más grandes).
- ¿Deberíamos hacer uso de memoria dinámica? Podríamos guardar cadenas todo lo grandes que quisiésemos pero gestionar memoria dinámica complica el diseño.

En cualquiera de los dos casos ahora tendríamos que copiar de forma explícita las cadenas ya que las asignaciones en el caso de punteros solo sirven para copiar direcciones de memoria...

```
class persona{
  char nombre[200];
  // ...
};

persona::persona(char *n,char *d,int c){
  // nombre = n; // error de compilacion
  strcpy(nombre,n); // se deberia usar strcpy_s. esto es un mero ejemplo
}
```

Asi que al final lo mejor es dejarse de tonterías de bajo nivel y usar `std::string` o `std::wstring`, que para eso están:

```
class persona {
  std::string nombre;
  std::string direccion;
};

persona::persona(std::string const& n, std::string const& d,int c){
  nombre = n;
  direccion = d;
}
```

Aunque ya puestos a hacerlo todo bien podemos aprovechar para iniciar las variables miembro usando su propio constructor:

```
persona::persona(std::string const& n, std::string const& d,int c)
  : nombre(n), direccion(d)
{ }
```

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo un ejemplo comentado, lo que hace es algo parecido al tuyo, usando operadores de ambito, metodos y propiedas.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Empleado {
    private:
        char* m_nombre;
        char* m_departamento;
        char* m_posicion;
        long m_salario;

    public:
        void ImprimirInfo();
        void SetNombre( char* nombre ) { m_nombre = nombre ;}
        void SetDepartamento( char * departamento) { m_departamento = departamento ;}
        void SetPosicion ( char* posicion ) { m_posicion = posicion ;}
        void SetSalario ( long salario ) { m_salario = salario ;}
        const char* GetNombre( ){ return m_nombre ;}
        const char* GetDepartamento( ){ return m_departamento ;}
        const char* GetPosicion( ){ return m_posicion; ;}
        const int GetSalario( ){ return m_salario; }
};

void Empleado::ImprimirInfo()
{
   cout << "Nombre: " << m_nombre << '\n';
   cout << "Departamento: " << m_departamento << '\n';
   cout << "Puesto: " << m_posicion << '\n';
   cout << "Salario: " << m_salario << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    //creacion de un objeto de la clase Empleado
    Empleado empleado12;

    //asignacion de valores a las variables miembro
    empleado12.SetNombre("Jose");
    empleado12.SetDepartamento("Sistemas");
    empleado12.SetPosicion("Programador");
    empleado12.SetSalario(3000000);

    //impresion de los datos
    empleado12.ImprimirInfo();
    return 0;
}
```

No se porque dicen que no compila, cuando a mi me anda bien. Y si marcan la pregunta como no util, deberian indicar porque la marcan como tal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: <iostream.h> me dice que no esta en directorio

Comment: prueba quitarle el .h y solo deja <iostream> que IDE usas para desarrollar?

Comment: dev c++  cual me recomiendas?

Comment: Yo uso codeblocks y trabajo bien alli

Comment: vere como me va con codeblocks gracias

Comment: Cualquier duda puedes preguntar, por aqui estare

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65218/discussion-between-luis-fernando-and-edwin-casco).

Comment: El código no hay por donde cogerlo... no compila y no es solamente por la cabecera que está mal (que ya que lo sabes podías haberlo corregido)

Comment: @eferion Subi una imagen ilustrativa para que veas que a mi me anda bien, puede ser por el iDE que usas.

Comment: @LuisFernando siente libre de probar el código que aparece en la respuesta [ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LVmsqJg2PFBYrlpe). La librería está mal y falta `std::` (o el `using` correspondiente). Por otro lado fíjate en los warnings del compilador, te estás saltando el tipado fuerte...

Comment: Lo de que la librería está mal ya está corregido en el ejemplo que te he puesto, no así en tu respuesta

Comment: Pero el problema es que a mi no me tira ni warnigs ni errores, por eso subi la respectiva imagen @eferion

Comment: Entonces tu codigo es diferente al de la respuesta. En cuanto a los warnings... lo mismo compilas enmascarando los errores

Comment: Bueno, solo queria ayudar, si se lo toman a mal que lastima. Que tengas buen dia. Hasta luego @eferion

Comment: No lo tomo a mal. Pero entiende que las respuestas deben ser correctas.  Aun asi echa un vistazo a mi respuesta... tu codigo sigue teniendo problemas aunque compile